# Oracle SQL required to convert rows into column depending on Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, decode, transpose

I have a table with the T1 with the following fields and data

```
SETID   Emplid          ITEM_NBR        CLASS   ITEM_AMT   ITEM_TYPE_CD     ITEM_NBR_SOURCE         Descr                   ACCOUNT_NBR
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000001 0       100         C                                       Health Services         HTL0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000002 0       5           C               000000000000001         VAT                     VAT0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000003 10149   150         C                                       Book Fee (10149)        BOOK001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000004 0       7.5         C               000000000000003         VAT                     VAT0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000005 10143   150         C                                       Book Fee (10143)        BOOK001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000006 0       7.5         C               000000000000005         VAT                     VAT0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000007 10190   150         C                                       Book Fee (10190)        BOOK001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000008 0       7.5         C               000000000000007         VAT                     VAT0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000009 0       350         C                                       Student Services        SSC0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000014 0       500         C                                       Registration Fees       REG0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000015 0       25          C               000000000000014         VAT                     VAT0001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000016 10149   2700        C                                       Principles of Economics TUT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000017 0       135         C               000000000000016         VAT                     VAT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000018 10143   3000        C                                       Operations Management   TUT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000019 0       150         C               000000000000018         VAT                     VAT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000020 10190   7000        C                                       TOEFL Package 1         TUPC001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000021 10149   -27         W                                       Reduction in VAT Waiver VAT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000022 10143   -30         W                                       Reduction in VAT Waiver VAT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000023 10149   -540        W                                       Discount                TUT001
KICAE   00000000261     000000000000024 10143   -600        W                                       Discount                TUT001
```

> I want to show two different fields "VAT" & Discount The VAT value is
> linked with ITEM_NBR_SOURCE and is always 5%  Item Type Code =C
> (Charge) ,W= Waiver The Discount Value and Reduction in VAT is linked
> with CLASS.  Any row where Course_title_long <>'VAT' and
> Course_title_long <>'Discount' should be displayed. ITEM_AMT for rows
> where Course_title_long ='VAT' and Course_title_long ='Discount',
> should be displayed in "Discount" & "VAT" column. Item_nbr_Source
> tells us the Source Item Number for that Charge(C) for that
> Item_Type_Cd ='W' is for Discount and Discount on VAT.
> ** Items which has ACCOUNT_NBR=TUT001 and Item_Type_Cd='C' has Discount
> Only**

The result being:

```
ITEM_NBR        Class   Descr                       ITEM_AMT       Discount     VAT(5%)   
000000000000001 0       Health Services             100             0            5
000000000000003 10149   Book Fee (10149)            150             0            7.5
000000000000005 10143   Book Fee (10143)            150             0            7.5
000000000000007 10190   Book Fee (10190)            150             0            7.5
000000000000009 0       Student Services            350             0            17.5
000000000000014 0       Registration Fees           500             0            25.0
000000000000016 10149   Principles of Economics     2700            540          135
000000000000018 10143   Operations Management       3000            600          150
000000000000020 10190   TOEFL Package 1             7000            0            350
000000000000021 10149   Reduction in VAT Waiver     540             0            27
000000000000022 10149   Reduction in VAT Waiver     600             0            30
```

Comment: Can you explain your result more? Which `ITEM_NBR` values to retain in the result? How will the query identify what to retain and what to convert to a column? How are the column values computed? We are not aware of your business logic

Comment: Hi Arijit, made the edits. Thanks pls let me know if this isn't clear still

Comment: The VAT part makes sense but what about the `ITEM_NBR_SOURCE` for `DISCOUNT` rows. How do they get in the final result? How to know which discount applies to which row?

Comment: DISCOUNT rows take CLASS_NBR into account. So for CLASS_NBR 10149, the row with ITEM_NBR 000000000000016 has AMOUNT and row with ITEM_NBR 000000000000023 has DISCOUNT value

Comment: How is the `ITEM_AMT` of  `Reduction in VAT Waiver` 540 and 600 and why is the `CLASS` same for both when they are not the same in the original data?

Comment: Also if the `CLASS` decides the discount, why is there 0 discount on the ITEM_NBRs `000000000000003` and `000000000000003`? They have `CLASS` where a discount is applied

Comment: Any Item with ACCOUNT_NBR=TUT0001 AND ITEM_TYPE_CD='C' has Discount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219245/discussion-between-rohit-prasad-and-arijit-kanrar).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, SO chat doesn't seem to work in our office network...